# Rake Test is failing

Tags: automated-tests, rake, cucumber

Snow Leopard, Test, Shoulda, Cucumber

I am running rake test and getting this error:

Any ideas?

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- RMagick
>   (MissingSourceFile)  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in
>   `require'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/app/models/business_profile_image.rb:24 
>   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in`
>   require'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in
>   `require_or_load'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in`
>   depend_on'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in
>   `require_dependency'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:393:in`
>   load_application_classes'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:392:in
>   `each'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:392:in`
>   load_application_classes'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:390:in
>   `each'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:390:in`
>   load_application_classes'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:195:in
>   `process'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`
>   send'  from
>   /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in
>   `run'  from /Users/rafaelparra/Sites/e2g2/config/environment.rb:14 
>   from ./test/unit/../test_helper.rb:2:in`require'  from
>   ./test/unit/../test_helper.rb:2  from ./test/unit/answer_test.rb:14:in
>   `require'  from ./test/unit/answer_test.rb:14  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in`
>   load'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
>   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in
>   `each'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
>   rake aborted! Command failed with status (1):
>   [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you re-compiled RMagic for Snow Leopard?

http://onrails.org/articles/2009/09/04/rmagick-from-source-on-snow-leopard